# Attempting to find date format for my android calendar events

Tags: android

I'm using this android calendar http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/ and attempting to populate it with events.

In the code below, it has an example of taking the dateCreated, which I assume is a timestamp, and does some sort of conversion on it. What does "dd" do?

I want to know what "day" is so I can tailor it to my own data.

```
         /**
                 * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
                 * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
                 * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
                 * day.
                 * 
                 * @param year
                 * @param month
                 * @return
                 */
                private HashMap findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year, int month)
                    {
                        System.out.println("BARGH!");
                        HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                        // DateFormat dateFormatter2 = new DateFormat();
                        //                      
                        // String day = dateFormatter2.format("dd", dateCreated).toString();
                        //
                        // if (map.containsKey(day))
                        // {
                        // Integer val = (Integer) map.get(day) + 1;
                        // map.put(day, val);
                        // }
                        // else
                        // {
                        // map.put(day, 1);
                        // }
                        return map;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the formatting options you have. For example 'dd' will give you the day of month in 2 digits.